# Use "member" table instead of "user" table for Yii authentication

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, yii, rbac

I have created a MySQL database table called "cc_member" which I was going to use for authentication, but after doing some research on Yii Authentication and RBAC.  All references I have found use a "user" table.  I would like to use the Yii Authentication system and I am wondering if I am banging my head against the wall trying to use "cc_member".  I might be far better off making the changes now and creating a "cc_user" table and go with the flow.

Does anyone else have any experience in using a table, other than "user" or "yii_user" etc. for Yii authentication?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how you name your database tables. The way you access them is through ActiveRecords, and they offer a function called `tableName` which - of course - returns the table name:

```
public function tableName()
{
    return 'cc_member';
}
```

The business logic how to authenticate against a database table is done within a `UserIdentity` class. See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUserIdentity) for more info.

For the autorisation process the function `checkAccess` of  `CWebUser` is called. Again, see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser) for more info.

Comment: Ophidian, 

I did some more research and it appears that I would need to override the "authenticate" function of CUserIdentity in a child class which extends it and call my model "member" from this function.  Here's an code snippet, where I've changed to user table to "member"...


class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $record=Member::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
}       

Is this pretty well it?

Comment: @user3604422: yes, and then check if the passwords match and return the result. A good example can be found here: [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#sec-1)